# Why does TreeView not load in loaded in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I am tring to create a `TreeView` with drag and drop functionality. I use this plugin 
http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-ui-tree, a demo is available here:

http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

But when I do the same thing things as written in the documentation my `TreeView`does not load - why?

Here is my code.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jm6a2zekeh9kixj/angular-ui-tree.min.css" />

    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nxy1if8uz0ndudn/angular-ui-tree.js?m="></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-controller="ctr">
<div ui-tree >
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node>
      <div ui-tree-handle>
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.items">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items" ui-tree-node>
          <div ui-tree-handle>
            {{subItem.title}}
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
  var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.tree']);
 myAppModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.item = [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "1. dragon-breath",
      "items": []
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "2. moiré-vision",
      "items": [{
        "id": 21,
        "title": "2.1. tofu-animation",
        "items": [{
          "id": 211,
          "title": "2.1.1. spooky-giraffe",
          "items": []
        }, {
          "id": 212,
          "title": "2.1.2. bubble-burst",
          "items": []
        }],
      }, {
        "id": 22,
        "title": "2.2. barehand-atomsplitting",
        "items": []
      }],
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "3. unicorn-zapper",
      "items": []
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "4. romantic-transclusion",
      "items": []
    }];
 }
</script>

</html>
```

Plunker :
http://plnkr.co/edit/ueIUs4pDnWIrRKbVhvDq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a syntax error, the last closing `)` is missing in the bottom script block.
2. The controller name is mismatch, the `MainCtrl` is registered but the `ctrl` is used in `ng-controller`.
3. In the first `ng-repeat="item in list"`, it loop over `$scope.list` but the data is in `$scope.item`.

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/crEDsbbN5e7wKVKbFPlZ?p=preview

Comment: oh shirt ..shilly mistakes..:(

Comment: but still there is issue demo look like that http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

Comment: is I not import css file

Comment: I think the `ui-tree` only provide the tree structure and drag&drop functionality. For styling, you are on your own. If you would like it to look the same as in the demo, you could copy the HTML and CSS from the demo directly.

Comment: wait checking for that ..I will tell you

Comment: The demo code is [here](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree/blob/master/demo/index.html), [CSS](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree/blob/master/demo/css/demo.css), and [JS](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree/blob/master/demo/js/demo.js)

Comment: i apply all css given in gtthub but no collabisible + and - display..:(

Comment: Please show what you have tried, may be an update plunker, we can start from that.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xur9RjMrhxEppNIewfo6?p=preview ..I think I choose wrong plugin ..I am trying to make like that http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: leave this Question I will doing RND ..going for other plugin.if you get time please look this Qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225579/getting-undefined-while-using-dynamice-form-plugin